# AngularJS подставляет знак восклицания в URL

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Неожиданно наткнулся на такую проблему: склонировал репозиторий проекта на другом компьютере (настроить коллеге). Обнаружил, что вместо одного `#` в url `#!` Соответственно никакие переходы не работают. Справедливо для всех браузеров.

Роутинг:

```
function route($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home',
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/user/list',
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/user/list.html',
            controller: 'userListCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
}
```

Попробовал склонировать в другую директорию на своем компе - все работает в штатном режиме.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Как ее лечить?

Comment: Так и не смог разобраться толком в чем проблема. Решил ее так: скопировал проект вручную с рабочего компа и перенес на подопытный комп. Запустил - работает. Дальше заменил все файлы под контролем версий файломи с локального компа - каких-то изменений не показало, но в итоге все работает.

Comment: стоит проверить настройки [hashPrefix](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider#hashPrefix)

Comment: В настройках не было hashPrefix, к тому же клонировалось из одного репозитория.